# Continuously updating textarea data to variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, textarea, updates

I want to get text from textarea to a string and update string content on change. Also, I want to make it without jQuery.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="switcher" oninput="update(this)" type="text" 
spellcheck="false" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" rows="1" 
cols="50" onkeyup="autoGrow(this)">text</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
let text = '',
    update = text => text = document.getElementById('switcher').value;
```

That's how I was trying to do it.

Maybe there is a way to do this nice with React or Angular but I don't know these frameworks.

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to accomlish

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to load data to variable immediately when something changes in textarea.

Comment: In other words you want to store the value?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes.

Comment: so it would be `update = textarea => text = textarea.value;`

Comment: It returns text undefined

Comment: not sure why...works for me

Comment: @charlietfl oh nice, thanks, it actually works! But is this a right way to do this? It this an alright practice?

Comment: More common practice these days to not use inline event listeners in the html and use things like [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener). Allows separating html from javascript code

Comment: I've used this to handle pressed buttons. But I'm not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: same as using `addEventListener('click', func...` but event is `"input"`  .... `document.getElementById('switcher').addEventListener('input', func`

Comment: And it will take any input? From keyboard and from pasting text? Is this input? Not oninput, as i've just read? There is also onpaste event

Comment: Yes except in older browsers that don't support oninput event Try yourself here https://jsfiddle.net/rk1j6ndp/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is getting passed the textarea object, to which you are then assigning a string. This makes no sense. Instead, you can try this:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const textarea = document.getElementById('text')
  textarea.oninput = function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  }
}
```

Then `this.value` in the `oninput` function stores the new value and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This is factually wrong. An inline method with `this` as parameter passes the element to the function as argument

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I still have so much to learn.